# How to handle case-insensitive keywords with Scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Some languages, like SQL, have case-insensitive keywords (and/or identifiers). When using `TokenParsers`, how can I handle this case insensitivity? One option is to generate all possible case combinations of keywords, but this performs quite badly if there are many keywords (in my case it somehow led to stack overflows in `whitespace`!) and won't work for the identifiers in any case.

[Self-answering in hope someone else won't end up spending a day on this.]

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by overriding `processIdent` (assumes keywords are given in upper case, as normal for SQL):

```
override protected def processIdent(name: String) = {
  val upperCased = name.toUpperCase
  if (reserved contains upperCased) Keyword(upperCased) else Identifier(upperCased)
}
```